# counting actual characters in a URI encoded string

Tags: c#

On the client, I have a textarea and I extract its value like this:

```
var TheURIEncodedString = encodeURI($('#TheTextArea').val());
```

The string then looks like this:

```
"This%20is%20a%20test%0AThis%20is%20a%20new%20line"
```

I send this string via ajax and when I receive it on the server, I need to count the number of actual characters, not the length of the string.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you consider un-escaping the string?

Comment: I'm open to all suggestions; can you show what that looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`HtppUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("This%20is%20a%20test%0AThis%20is%20a%20new%20line").Length;
```

Result:

```
This is a test
This is a new line
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the  [HtppUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) method

```
int numberOfCharacters = 
    HttpUtility.UrlDecode("This%20is%20a%20test%0AThis%20is%20a%20new%20line").Length;
```